# Get session from outside service class in GWT

Tags: gwt, guice, httpsession

I successfully use the session in my services using :

```
getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()
```

However my application being separated in layers, a method from my service will call another method from Business layer, then calling DAO layer methods.

In DAO layer I would like to access some information kept in session. 
Here is the way I can see :

- Pass the HttpSession object in every methods ... But I don't want to do that

Are there other ways to do that ?

I'm using GUICE for information, is there some already created provider which would give me the current request session ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried @Inject Provider<HttpSession>  sessionProvider;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application is already layered, why 'pollute' your DAO layer with something so implementation-specific as an HTTPSession object? That's certainly not the way to go from an architectural point of view. It also makes unit testing harder.

Comment: You're right, since these infos came from Php session I didn't though about it and wanted to put them in Java session. But to keep my layers on track, I'll use the DAO layer to get the info I need.